# How can I exclude some keys from an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, lodash

I am working on the render method of a datatable component where I have to filter some headers.

I have this:

```
  <TableRow>
    {headers.map(header =>
      checkboxes.map(checkbox =>
          // HERE I NEED TO FILTER IT
        checkbox.value === header.key && checkbox.checked && (
          <TableHeader {...getHeaderProps({ header })}>               
            {header.header}
          </TableHeader>
        ),
      ),
    )}
  </TableRow>
```

The `checkbox.checked` you see above returns `true` or `false` and I need 2 keys to ignore from those conditionals. It doesn't matter if the conditionals are met.

Here I am checking that the values of `checkbox` and `header` are the same `checkbox.value === header.key` but I need to exclude 2 `header.key` which are `header.key === device` and `header.key === ticketNumber`.

So I need to do something like:

```
 <TableRow>
    {headers.map(header =>
      checkboxes.map(checkbox =>
          // HERE I NEED TO FILTER IT
        checkbox.value === header.key && checkbox.checked && (ignore header.key === 'device' && header.key === 'ticketNumber' from the conditionals above) (
          <TableHeader {...getHeaderProps({ header })}>               
            {header.header}
          </TableHeader>
        ),
      ),
    )}
  </TableRow>
```

I mean, those 2 headers I mentioned in the code above should never be hidden from the UI. When this condition `checkbox.value === header.key && checkbox.checked` is met, it will hide all of the headers with `checkbox.checked === true`, but I need a proper condition/function to ignore the header keys `header.key === device` and `header.key === ticketNumber`. Those 2 headers should always exist in the UI.

I am using lodash, I don't know if I can use it there or if there are any other options?

Comment: So use array.filter().map()

Answer (score 3):

If I correctly understand your requirements, I think this should work:

```
<TableRow>
  {headers.map(header =>
     (['device', 'ticketNumber'].includes(header.key) || checkboxes.find(checkbox => header.key === checkbox.value).checked) && 
       <TableHeader {...getHeaderProps({ header })}>               
         {header.header}
       </TableHeader>
  )}
</TableRow>
```

Comment: Mmm and what this does `.map(checkbox =>`? If I leave it as you set it here, it only shows those 2 headers across the whole row of headers.

Comment: I missed the `header.key === checkbox.value` conditional - updated

Comment: It is showing nothing. I don't get why `.map(checkbox =>` because `checkbox` is never going to be use.

Comment: Actually with that last update what I get is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined` and in the `.map(checkbox =>...` part says `checkbox is defined but never used`

Comment: do you have one checkbox per header?

Comment: No. I have 6 headers and only 4 checkboxes. The checkboxes don't apply for `device` and `ticketNumber`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a simple `shouldShow()` method outside of the component. The method should include your conditions, and return a boolean.

Since you've got 3 checkboxes, and you only want to show the relevant column, when one of them is checked, you should remove the 2nd map, and use `Array.some()` to check if at least one of the is `checked`, and it's `value` is the same `value` of the key.

**Note:** You don't need to actually filter the array, because react ignores `false` values in render (see [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator)). It also ignores `undefined`, and `null`.

```
const shouldShow = ({ key }, checkboxes) =>
  key === 'device' || 
  key === 'ticketNumber' || 
  checkboxes.some(({ checked, value }) => checked && value === key);

<TableRow>
  {headers.map(header =>
    shouldShow(header, checkboxes) && (
      <TableHeader {...getHeaderProps({ header })}>               
        {header.header}
      </TableHeader>
    ),
  )}
</TableRow>
```

A better solution would to create a Set of checked keys using `Array.reduce()`, and then check if the key exists in it while rendering the columns:

```
 // in the render method
const shouldRenderSet = checkboxes.reduce((r, { checked, value }) =>
  checked ? r.add(value) : r
, new Set(['device', 'ticketNumber'])) 

<TableRow>
  {headers.map(header =>
    shouldRenderSet.has(header.key) && (
      <TableHeader {...getHeaderProps({ header })}>               
        {header.header}
      </TableHeader>
    ),
  )}
</TableRow>
```